# Выбрать топ продуктов

Tags: mysql, sql

Присутствуют две таблицы.

Детали заказов: ProductID-id продукта, Quantity-количество проданного товара

```
CREATE TABLE #OrderDetails (ProductID nvarchar(50), Quantity nvarchar(50));
INSERT INTO #OrderDetails VALUES
('111','2'),
('222','2'), 
('333','1'),
('444','3'), 
('555','5'), 
('666','1');
```

И информация о продукте: ProductID-id продукта, ProductName-название продукта

```
CREATE TABLE #Products (ProductID nvarchar(50), ProductName nvarchar(50));
INSERT INTO #Products VALUES
('111','Apple'),
('222','Nokia'), 
('333','Acer'),
('444','Samsung'), 
('555','HP'), 
('666','LG');
```

Требуется вывести имена и ID пяти самых покупаемых продуктов. А также сколько их было продано.

Comment: из таблицы какой структуры это надо сделать? или информация из разных таблиц будет? приведите пример таблицы/таблиц.

Comment: Никому не надо ходить по "левым" ссылкам. 100% вопроса должны быть здесь.

Answer (score 2):

Берете заказы, джойните продукты, считаете число товаров в заказах, группируете по ним  и сортируете по убыванию. берете первые 5.

```
SELECT p.ProductName, sum(Quantity) as q
FROM OrderDetails AS o
INNER JOIN Products AS p ON p.ProductID = o.ProductID
GROUP BY p.ProductName
ORDER BY SUM(Quantity) DESC
```

в тэгах у вас указана mysql тогда в конец `LIMIT 5`. Но поскольку данный вариант вызывает ошибку, то видимо там не mysql и работать в песочнице будет вариант `SELECT TOP 5`

*зы: структуру таблиц и примеры данных надо включать в вопрос, а не по внешним ссылкам*